# css - Table immune to browser zoom

Tags: css

Ok, i have a wordpress site, i added a table and use the

white-space: no-wrap;

Since i want the table headers to stay on a single line, the table have too many headers and need to make to stay outside of the content "boundary" (that is fine with me).

The problem is that when i zoom in and out with the browser, the table change position (moves a lil bit left or right and dosnt stay centered) i center it manualy with the "margin".

Im very new to css, hope i describe the issue enough.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .tablepress {
white-space: nowrap;
clear: both;
margin-left: -50px;
```

}

```
.entry table {
border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
background-color: #F9F9F9;
width: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: Arial,"Bitstream Vera Sans",Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
color: #333;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
}


.tablepress {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 1em;
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: please provide full html and css of your table otherwise we'll just be guessing at what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Does setting a width not work?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table{border:1px solid #000;width:100%}
```

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZrHs/)

It might also help if you provided a little more information, like where abouts on your page you want to put this table

Comment: I updated the question. However the width:100% has no effect at all.

Comment: Can you also provide the HTML? I can't tell what styles go where, and whether there are multiple places one style is applied to without it.